# Problems clearing a UILabel from an NSString?

Tags: ios

I am implementing a UIlabel that displays the result of a user's button clicks using an NSString. When the user presses a button, a string is created and the current title of the button is appended to the string. That part works well, and I don't need any advice. What I am having trouble with is clearing the string when the user presses a "clear" button. I tried setting the display to nil when the button is pressed. This clears it, but won't let any new input be added again. It just stays blank until the app is closed. Any advice on the most simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the label's `text` property to `@""` (an empty string), not `nil`.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a bunch. Knew there was a simple way that I was missing.